# Как сделать возможность клиентам подключить свой домен к моему сервису

Tags: php, dns, domain

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Есть сервис, который позволяет клиентам создавать свою страничку. Страничка открывается следующим образом: https://mysite.ru/page/id.
Как мне реализовать возможность клиентам подключать свой домент?
Например: https://clientdomain.ru будет ссылаться к https://my.site.ru/page/clientId

Comment: Для этого клиент должен отредактировать свои DNS записи и добавить CNAME со своим доменом, указывающим на ваш адрес. Не думаю что кто-то даст вам доступ к DNS записям клиента, так что делать это им придётся самостоятельно.

Comment: Это я понимаю. А как мне со своей стороны это организовать? Мне нужно создать конфигурацию nginx для домена клиента? Чтобы он ссылался на определенную страницу моего сайта?

Comment: Вам нужно у себя создать, с примеру, субдомен для клиента, либо определённый путь только для его сайта в NGINX. Клиент у себя в DNS делает настройку что запросы на его домен будут уходить на ваш сайт через CNAME. Все.